# How to put a number from a csv file into an HTML table?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I have made a web scraper to gather Corona-virus data. I know this type of website has been done before but I want to do it for personal enjoyment and also I am a beginner so I thought it would be a good first website...

Anyways, I need to get my data from the web scraper into an HTML table to display the proper deaths and cases. I have one python code file to get the deaths for just one country and one to get the cases. I have the scraped data saving in a csv if there is anyway I can just get that number in my HTML code.

I guess what I am asking is is there anyway to take that number and just put it in an HTML table code?

Comment: the data per country is available on github (Hopkins), you may want to check : https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19

Comment: @BertrandMartel I want to do it my self and I need to get that data into a html table.

Comment: Yes, there are ways of doing that. Details will depend on how you're getting the number from the CSV file and how you're building the HTML table — however there's no clue or code in your question…

Comment: You can use csv and sys, but as @martineau pointed out, there is no way on what yo want to do.

Comment: I didnt think I would need to include my code because it is just a simple html table with tr and td tags. There is nothing really special. I have the number in a csv file. Is there any way I can set that csv file to a variable and call for it in html?

Answer (score 0):

`HTML` is normal string. You can use string functions to create string with `HTML` with data in `<table>` and save in file to display in web browser.

Use `for`-loop to convert every row of data to string with `<tr>` and add to rest of `HTML`.

You can also use `Jinja` to use file with template (like in web framework `Flask`) but still it needs `for`-loop inside template to generate rows.

This way you have full control on `HTML`.

---

You can also use `to_html` in `pandas`

```
df = pandas.read_csv(filename, ...)
html = df.to_html()
```

to get `HTML` only with `<table>` which you can save in file and display or you can add to other `HTML`.

[to_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) has some options to change something in `<table>` but probably you don't have full control on this table.

---

**EDIT:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")

df.to_html("file.html")

# or

table = df.to_html()
print(table)

html = "<html> <head></head> <body>" + table + "</body> </html>"

fp = open("file.html", "w")
fp.write(html)
fp.close()
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you have data in separated files `China.csv`, `UK.csv`, etc. then use `for`-loop

```
`# --- before loop ---

HTML = "<html> <head><title>All Countries</title> </head> <body>"

# --- loop ---

for country in ['China', 'UK', 'Italy']:
    df = pd.read_csv( country + '.csv' )
    table = df.to_html()
    HTML += "<h1>" + country + "</h1>" + table

# --- after loop ---

HTML += "</body> </html>"    
#print(HTML)

fp = open("output.html", "w")
fp.write(HTML)
fp.close()
```

And if you have all CSV files in folder ie. `data` then you can use `os.listdir()` or `glob.glob()`

```
# --- before loop ---

HTML = "<html> <head><title>All Countries</title> </head> <body>"

folder = 'data'

# --- loop ---

for filename in sorted(os.listdir(folder)):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        country = filename.replace('.csv', '')

        fullpath = os.path.join(folder, filename)

        df = pd.read( fullpath )
        table = df.to_html()

        HTML += "<h1>" + country + "</h1>" + table

# --- after loop ---

HTML += "</body> </html>"    
#print(HTML)

fp = open("output.html", "w")
fp.write(HTML)
fp.close()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Using string function to create HTML with table.

```
import pandas as pd

# --- example data ---

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [  1,   2,   3],
    'B': ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
    'C': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
})

# --- before loop ---

HTML = """<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
   <title>Example Data</title>
</head>

<body>

"""

# --- loop ---

HTML += '<table>\n'

# headers

HTML += '  <tr>\n'
for header in df.columns:
    HTML += '    <th>' + str(header) + '</th>\n'

HTML += '  </tr>\n'

# rows

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    HTML += '  <tr>\n'
    for cell in row:
        HTML += '    <td>' + str(cell) + '</td>\n'
    HTML += '  </tr>\n'

HTML += '</table>\n'

# --- after loop ---

HTML += """
</body>

</html>"""

# --- end ---

print(HTML)
```

Result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
   <title>Example Data</title>
</head>

<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>0.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Y</td>
    <td>0.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Z</td>
    <td>0.3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

The same using `pandas` `to_html()`

```
import pandas as pd

# --- example data ---

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [  1,   2,   3],
    'B': ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
    'C': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
})

# --- before loop ---

HTML = """<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
   <title>Example Data</title>
</head>

<body>

"""

# --- loop ---

HTML += df.to_html()

# --- after loop ---

HTML += """
</body>

</html>"""

# --- end ---

print(HTML)
```

Result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
   <title>Example Data</title>
</head>

<body>

<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>0.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Y</td>
      <td>0.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Z</td>
      <td>0.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So in the () with csv do I put the csv file name?

Comment: yes, you put filename and many other options - like separator, skip headers, etc. See doc [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: I am still confused. Would you want to help me more over email? Its okay if you dont want to. I am a beginner at coding I just really need help

Comment: what is the problem ? `import pandas` `df = pandas.read_csv("file.csv")` `html = df.to_html()` `print(html)` eventually `df.to_html("file.html")`

Comment: but what do I do on the html side of things so I import that data exactly where I want it?

Comment: it generates only `<table>` as string and you can add it to other HTML (which is also string)

Comment: So what does that mean. Also Im sorry if I sound like a nucense

Comment: do you know HTML ? You get only string with "<table><tr><td>value</td>...</table>" and you can save it in file and web browser will display it. OR you can add more string to this table to have more information on page and save new string - see new example in answer.

Comment: Oh I understand. It will only print a one line table correct? My other problem with that would be that I need to make a code for each country. With this, I would be unavle to import all of that data into just one table

Comment: not one line but full table with all data from CSV. You can read different CSV files, generate different tables (strings) and join these tables (strings) to one string which you can save in one HTML file. And then you have one page with many tables - one table for each country.

Comment: BTW: if you want one table with all coutries (instead of one table for each country) then you should learn `pandas` because it has many functions to work with data from `csv`, `excel`, `database`

Comment: is there anyway to make a mega code for all countries though?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean mega code - if you want to read data from many files - one file for one country - then use `for`-loop with `df = pd.read_csv() table = df.to_html()` to create many tables and later join them to one string. I already mentioned it in one of previous comment.

Comment: BTW: I added examples with `for`-loop.

Comment: Nevermind. Thank you so much that really helped out a lot.

Comment: what do I do on the side of the html? Like how does this know where to send the data?

Comment: do you mean send to file ? If you use `df.to_html(filename)` then it send HTML to file. If you use `html = df.to_html()` then you have all HTML in variable `html`. If you mean how `to_html()` knows in which row put values - it use `for`-loop to get rows from DataFrame, and nested `for`-loop to get value from row - and then it create string `"<td>" + str(value) + "<td>"`, and later it join it with `"<tr>" + ... + "</tr>"`, and later it join it with `"<table>" +  ... + "</table>"`. You can use `for`-loops to write own code which creates `<table> ... </table>`

Comment: how do I do this though. As you may infer, I am very much so a beginner. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: in my answer you have already examples how to create `HTML` using `for`-loop.

Comment: I understand however I just dont really know how to implement it into my code.

Comment: I added full working code which generates full `HTML` using some example data.

Comment: if you use pandas then you need only `HTML += df.to_html()`

Comment: Okay thank you. I can use the data from the csv file to do this right?

Comment: use `df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")` to use `csv file` - you have it in one of previous examples.

Comment: sorry to bother you again but where you said ```df = pandas``` then you manually imported a table I was just and still am confused as to how I do that for my data. Like what do I put there?

Comment: in question you wrote that you have data in CSV file then use `df = pd.read_csv("your file.csv")` instead of `df = pd.DataFrame({...})` and rest of code is the same.